# cd cannot find the file in bash

Tags: bash, cd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I'm using bash the cd command does not work and says their is no such file or directory even though it exists.

```
hudson@DESKTOP:~$ cd C:\Users\Hudson\Desktop\Rake\SportBukkit-master
bash: cd: C:UsersHudson: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Turn your slash around and your golden `cd C:/Users/Hudson/Desktop/Rake/SportBukkit-master`

Comment: Looks like he's using Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: 1. As @JNevill said. 2. Check TAB – that magic key on your keyboard can make magic (auto-completing command, dir, filename...).

Comment: @Sylogista I'm guessing by that `master` that maybe this is git bash? Either way if you are in a linux type environment then your directories are separated with a `/`

Comment: @JNevill I've since few weeks Windows 10 and Ubuntu on it gives me prompt just like that. Especially ``DESKTOP``. That ``*Bukkit-master`` looks like git – true.

Comment: @Cyrus *Your question is better suited to Super User.*  `bash` shell scripts are also programming - hence the `bash` tag.  I'm not convinced this is off-topic.

Comment: By the way I'm using Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem Linux.

Comment: @JNevill I tried switching to using / or // and moving the folder to my C: drive and it still gives me the `bash: cd: C:SportBukkit-master: No such file or directory`

Comment: See "how do I access my c drive" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is the escape character.  Per [the Advanced Scripting guide at the Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#ESCP):

> Escaping is a method of quoting single characters. The escape ()
>   preceding a character tells the shell to interpret that character
>   literally.
>
> Special meanings of certain escaped characters
>
> ...
>
> \n
>
> means newline
>
> \r
>
> means return
>
> \t
>
> means tab
>
> \v
>
> means vertical tab
>
> \b
>
> means backspace
>
> \a
>
> means alert (beep or flash)

Since `\U` isn't special, it's interpreted as a simple `U`.

Hence your input of

```
hudson@DESKTOP:~$ cd C:\Users\Hudson\Desktop\Rake\SportBukkit-master
```

results in the error message

```
bash: cd: C:UsersHudson: No such file or directory
```

Because `\U` is `U` etc.

You need to enter

```
hudson@DESKTOP:~$ cd C:\\Users\\Hudson\\Desktop\\Rake\\SportBukkit-master
```

So the `\\` gets interpreted as a single `\`.

Or, as noted in the comments, use `/`.

Comment: And remember – in that case using ``/`` is better, you can use tabulator while command writing.